# Is div within select valid?

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, marionette

Is it valid to add a div within select tags?

Using Marionette, I have a compositeview that uses "select" as an itemViewContainer.
The options are dynamically loaded from the server.
In case no options are available, I want to load an emptyview instead using div (no option).

Is it valid to load a div as emptyview within the select?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No; the only valid child elements of a `<select>` element are `<option>` or `<optgroup>` elements; `<div>` elements are not permitted; not even if you try to wrap them inside of an `<option>` (which can contain only text).

References:

- [MDN `<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select).
- [W3 `<select>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/forms.html#the-select-element).

Comment: Ok, then I'll need to replace the entire select. Acceptance soon.